# In Postgresql, how to un-invert the timezone offsets with "At Time Zone"

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm trying to wrap my head around Postgresql timezones, and I can't seem to figure this out. EST is "Eastern Standard Time" in America, and is typically [UTC-5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone).

Example 1: Base Test

```
select '08/31/2011 12:00 pm EST'::timestamptz  at time zone 'EST';
      timezone       
---------------------
 2011-08-31 12:00:00
```

Example 2: Offset is +5

```
select '08/31/2011 12:00 pm EST' at time zone '+5';
      timezone       
---------------------
 2011-08-31 12:00:00
```

Example 3: Offset is -5

```
 select '08/31/2011 12:00 pm EST' at time zone '-5';
      timezone       
---------------------
 2011-08-31 22:00:00
```

Clearly, everything is backwards. EST is again... [supposed to be UTC-5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone). Now, I did search through documentation, and it does explain that things are "POSIX", [which is backwards](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES). (Positive offset is west of GMT, while negative offsets are east of GMT).

However, how do I get around this? At the application layer, I can always invert the + sign to a - sign, but that seems a bit messy to me IMO. Thus, my ultimate question.

At the database layer (Postgres), is there a way to use the "At Time Zone" syntax so that GMT-5 corresponds to EST? Or do I just have to invert everything at the application layer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use interval datatype as written in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) to get proper behaviour:

> In these expressions, the desired time zone `zone` can be specified
>   either as a text string (e.g., 'PST') or as an **interval** (e.g.,
>   INTERVAL '-08:00').

*Base test:*

```
SELECT '08/31/2011 12:00 pm EST'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'EST';
      timezone       
---------------------
 2011-08-31 12:00:00
(1 row)
```

*Timezone info:*

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_abbrevs WHERE abbrev LIKE 'EST';
 abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst 
--------+------------+--------
 EST    | -05:00:00  | f
(1 row)
```

*Proper offset -5:*

```
SELECT '08/31/2011 12:00 pm EST'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE '-05:00'::interval;
      timezone       
---------------------
 2011-08-31 12:00:00
(1 row)
```

*Proper offset +5:*

```
SELECT '08/31/2011 12:00 pm EST'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE '+05:00'::interval;
      timezone       
---------------------
 2011-08-31 22:00:00
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find this feature documented anywhere. Do you know where you learned about this?

Comment: @Dragontamer5788: Sure, I found this on http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Behavior-of-quot-at-time-zone-quot-td1928049.html

Comment: Lol. That link you have has a link to the Postgresql Documentation. Oh well, I guess I just didn't read all of the manual. Thanks for the link, I guess I'll just read more carefully next time.