# Postgres time zone offset not working as expected

Tags: postgresql

As per Postgres documentation `at time zone` can take ISO-8601 style time offset or standard time zone abbreviation.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONE-TABLE

IST stands for ISRAEL STANDARD TIME in Postgres and has an offset of +02:00. 
Example When it is Wednesday 12:00 AM at Greenwich (GMT), it is Wednesday 02:00 AM at Israel (IST)

So the follwing 2 statements should be equivalent:

```
select cast('2012-07-02 00:00:00' as timestamp without time zone) at time zone 'IST';

select cast('2012-07-02 00:00:00' as timestamp without time zone) at time zone '+02:00';
```

but they are not. Both statements give different results.

Changing `+02:00` to `-02:00` solves the problem. This behavior is inconsistent with the documentation. Am I missing something? What I understand from the documentation (and also general convention) is that time zones to the east of GMT have positive offset and those to the right have negative offset. So whats going on here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117355/in-postgresql-how-to-un-invert-the-timezone-offsets-with-at-time-zone

Comment: ISO 8601 and POSIX use opposite signs in timezones, you're using one but PostgreSQL is interpreting it as the other one. Hooray for standards!